# Can't cumulate the sum of array elements with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, sum

I'm trying to cumulate the sums of values in an excel column of 4 values dimension (4,1).

So, I constructed the code below. For the first row in a column on the side Result, it is supposed to hold the same value as in the original Array. 
But then, once it is greater than the first row, it is supposed to get the previous element of result (i-1) and add to it the current column element (i).

VBA is telling me that the subscript is out of range :/ and I cant figure out why... so I dont even know if my code does what I want.

```
Sub CumulativeSum()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim rColumn() As Variant
    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(1 To 4)
    rColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E4").Value2

    For i = 1 To 4
        result(1) = rColumn(1, 1)
        For j = 2 To 3
            result(j) = rColumn(j, 1) + result(j - 1)
        Next j
   Next i
   Dim dest As Range
   Set dest = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1")
   dest.Resize(4, 1).Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: This code would not compile.  You've left something out.

Comment: all arrays start at index 0 unless specified by using Option Base 1 or in the declaration of the array Dim vArray(1 To 5). You also need to initalize the arrays as they currently have no elements.  You are also missing the "end if"

Comment: I have a new code, and I added Option Base 1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub CumulativeSum()

    Dim dest As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim rColumn() As Variant
    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(1 To 4)
    rColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E4").Value2

    result(1) = rColumn(1, 1)
    For j = 2 To 4
        result(j) = rColumn(j, 1) + result(j - 1)
    Next j

    Set dest = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1")
    dest.Resize(4, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(result)

End Sub
```

Comment: Got a question... if I decided I would like to get the values from the range by using Range(Cells(5,1), Cells(5,4)).Value, would that work? Cause I tried it on a file and it returned type mismatch... :S

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough rep to add a comment but.. the reason why you're getting an error is because the Syntax for Cells is Cells([Row],[Column]). You're typing it in as Cells([Column],[Row]).

Try Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(4, 5)) instead.